# Sending email from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sendmail, email-validation, smtplib

I am trying to send email from python  using smtp server but it throws the 
error. How can I solve it?
I also have get permission from gmail to use this feature
Here is the code

```
import smtplib


content='Hello I am just checking email.'
mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('My email','Mypassword')
mail.send('From email','destiation password',content)
mail.close()
```

This code throws this error
    TypeError: send() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Please fix this error.

Comment: try `sendmail` instead of `send`

Answer (score 4):

`sendmail` is what you should use:

```
smtplib.SMTP.sendmail(self, from_addr, to_addrs, msg, mail_options=[], rcpt_options=[])
```

> This command performs an entire mail transaction.
>
> The arguments are:

```
- from_addr    : The address sending this mail.
- to_addrs     : A list of addresses to send this mail to.  A bare
                 string will be treated as a list with 1 address.
- msg          : The message to send.
- mail_options : List of ESMTP options (such as 8bitmime) for the
                 mail command.
- rcpt_options : List of ESMTP options (such as DSN commands) for
                 all the rcpt commands.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import smtplib 
import email
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.parser import Parser
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEAudio import MIMEAudio
import mimetypes

def send(user, password, fromaddr, to, subject, body):
smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect(smtp_host,smtp_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(user, password)

msg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = email.Utils.COMMASPACE.join(to)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
server.sendmail(user,to,msg.as_string())
```